# Many pages handled by single PHP file vs many PHP files

Tags: php, indexing

I 'm currently building a website which I 'd like to launch in the future. I have build a lot already and have around 40 pages I think. The website currently works like this if you go to another link:

/index.php

*click on link to members*

/members.php

I could however also make place all logic in my index.php:

/index.php

*click on link to members*

/index.php?action=members

My question however is, what is the advantage of such approach, when many pages are served by single entry scrypt? What would I gain? Is it worth rewriting my site?

Comment: allows you to hide your process code away from individual pages meaning you can load your overall template/headers/footers etc in the index.php and your sub pages contain only the code relevent to those pages.  also makes it easier if you're looking to make pretty/clean url's should you want to in future.

Comment: I see, so it is useful when you want to take a look at your code and not needing to change the template/headers/footers again. Would it also make it easier to change a site style if I would add the option to change styles? By the way, why is everyone downvoting my question?

Comment: yes very if used correctly obviously like anything it can be badly implemented but if used right can make your entire project alot more sensible and is at heart how all frameworks work with their pretty url's there's always the primary controler index.php which then loads the included methods/views etc based off the requested pretty url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you mean is serving static content vs dynamic content.

If you use URLs with a query string, i.e. `http://domain.com/index.php?site=foo`, the developer has usually built a static frame around dynamic content. That means things like HTML Header, logo, navigation, footer and other things are static and he does not need to keep that information in every file. The content is then loaded from different files, which do just have to keep the content.

One negative site, or at least many people think that way, is that your URLs do not look nice and are not so well readable by humans and search spiders. A technique to impose static URLs on dynamic URLs is to use mod_rewrite and a .htaccess file. You can tell the webserver that certain locations from your URL are the equivalent to the URL with a query string. For example `http://domain.com/list/` is the equivalent to `http://domain.com/index.php?site=list`.

The dynamic content is easily achieved like here. You can trigger the dynamic content loading by using an URL with a query string, e.g. `http://domain.com/index.php?site=list`.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<!-- html header -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation>
<!-- your navigation -->
</div>
<div id="content">
<?php
switch($_GET['site'])
{
   case "list":
      // serve list content
      include("list.php");
      break;

   default:
      // server default content
      include("home.php");
      break;
}
?>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<!-- your footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `switch()` function does prope for the value of `$_GET['site']` and serves the content based on the match of the cases.

An example .htaccess file can be found here that uses URLs without trailing slashes: (You just need to make sure that mod_rewrite is active for your Apache (a2enmod rewrite @ linux) or your similar web server. Alternatively you can also write that into your vhost configuration file.)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)[/\?]$
      RewriteRule ^(.*)[/\?]$ $1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
      RewriteRule ^([^\./]+)/([^\./]+)/([^\./]+)/([^\./]+)$ index.php?section=$1&sub=$2&sub2=$3&sub3=$4 [L]
      RewriteRule ^([^\./]+)/([^\./]+)/([^\./]+)$ index.php?section=$1&sub=$2&sub2=$3 [L]
      RewriteRule ^([^\./]+)/([^\./]+)$ index.php?section=$1&sub=$2 [L]
      RewriteRule ^([^\./]+)$ index.php?section=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I see, so the advantage is not having to include the footer, header, logo etc. again in every file?

Comment: yep, this is the big advantage

Comment: So if you use mod_rewrite you don't have to rewrite all your pages but can tell the code to automatically write it like index.php?site=

Comment: I would upvote you if I could, but for some reason after I said something to Taxicala all my questions got downvoted? :S

Comment: Note in his example above its massively insecure but the concept is the same it just needs re-writing to not do blind trusting file includes

Comment: I see, so you would recommend to rewrite all the PHP files instead of using mod_rewrite if I would want to implent this?

Comment: Dave, what do you mean with file includes?